# I have a calendar I want to append text to today's <td>

Tags: javascript

Edited with my latest findings...... I am able to appendChild to the TD correlating to today using

```
const td1 = document.getElementById('todaycell');
    const text = document.createTextNode("Total Units = ");
td1.appendChild(text);
  };
```

I want to first add a p tag as the child of td and then create the text node. lastly I want to appendChild to the p tag.
How would I accomplish this?

I'll post my code below. https://codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/YzvQBmW

```js
let CURR_DATE = new Date();

const MONTHS = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December'
];

function getTotalDaysInMonth(year, month) {
 
  return 32 - new Date(year, month, 32)
    .getDate();
}

const grid = document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-table td');
const dateText = document.getElementById('date-text');


const calendarTitle = document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-title')[0];

// clears all cells
function clearGrid() {
  grid.forEach(cell => {
    cell.innerHTML = '';
    cell.removeAttribute("id", 'todaycell');
  });
}

function renderCalendar(date = CURR_DATE) {
  clearGrid();
  
  // sets month and year
  calendarTitle.innerText = `${MONTHS[date.getMonth()]}, ${date.getFullYear()}`;
  
  const dayOfWeek  = date.getDay();
  const dateOfMnth = date.getDate();
  
  let totalMonthDays = getTotalDaysInMonth(
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth()
  );
  
  let startDay = dayOfWeek - dateOfMnth % 7 + 1;
  
  if (startDay < 0)
    startDay = (startDay + 45) % 7;
  
  for ( let i = startDay; i < totalMonthDays + startDay; i++ )
    grid[i % 45].innerHTML = (i - startDay + 1);
  let today = new Date()
  if (today.toDateString() === date.toDateString()) {
    grid[(startDay + dateOfMnth - 1) % 45].setAttribute("id", 'todaycell')
const td1 = document.getElementById('todaycell');
    const text = document.createTextNode("Total Units = ");
td1.appendChild(text);
  };
  
  dateText.innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
  
}
[...document.getElementsByClassName('button')].forEach(button => {
  
  let incr = 1;
  // left button decreases month
  if (button.classList.contains('buttonPrevious'))
    incr = -1;
  
  button.onclick = function() {
    CURR_DATE.setMonth(CURR_DATE.getMonth() + incr);
    renderCalendar(); 
  };
  let today = new Date()
  const tdate = document.querySelector("#date-text"); 
  tdate.onclick = function () {
      CURR_DATE = new Date();
    renderCalendar(today); 
  };
  
})
//clearGrid()
renderCalendar();
```

```css
body {
    background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.tabalign{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.tab{
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block-wrapper, .spacing{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.tile {
    background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.spacing{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

button{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn ,#date-text{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button, .btn, #date-text{
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}
.buttonPrevious, .buttonNext{
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
}

#date-text{
  display: flex;
  justify: center;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
}

.buttonPrevious{
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.buttonNext{
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.btncontainer{
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top:20px;
}

#calendar-container {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#calendar-title {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  
}

#calendar-table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 970px;
  height: 100%;
}

#calendar-table td{
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid rgb(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
}

  th{
  vertical-align: top;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
} 

#todaycell {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 25px;
}


p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="tabs">
     <div class="tabalign">
     <button class="btn tab" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">
                    Back To Unit Counter
                </button>
     </div>
   </header>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="tile">
    <div id="calendar-container">
      <table id="calendar-table">
        <div class="spacing">
        <span class="btncontainer"> 
        <button class="button buttonPrevious"><</button>
            <h1 id="calendar-title">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span> 
      </h1>
          <button class="button buttonNext">></button>
          </div>
          </s>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tue</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thu</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="td1"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="date-text"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <script  src="./cal.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
  dateText.innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
  
}
[...document.getElementsByClassName('button')].forEach(button => {
  
  let incr = 1;
  // left button decreases month
  if (button.classList.contains('buttonPrevious'))
    incr = -1;
  
  button.onclick = function() {
    CURR_DATE.setMonth(CURR_DATE.getMonth() + incr);
    renderCalendar(); 
  };
  let today = new Date()
  const tdate = document.querySelector("#date-text"); 
  tdate.onclick = function () {
    renderCalendar(today); 
  };
  
})
//clearGrid()
renderCalendar();
```

```css
body {
    background: #000000;
  height: 100vh;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.tabalign{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.tab{
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.block-wrapper, .spacing{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.tile {
    background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.spacing{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

button{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn ,#date-text{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button, .btn, #date-text{
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}
.buttonPrevious, .buttonNext{
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#date-text{
  display: flex;
  justify: center;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
}

.buttonPrevious{
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.buttonNext{
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#calendar-container {
  background-color: black;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#calendar-title {
  display:inline;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  
}

#calendar-table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 970px;
  height: 100%;
}

#calendar-table td{
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid rgb(80, 80, 80, 0.5);
}

  th{
  vertical-align: top;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
} 

.todayCell {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 25px;
}


p{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header class="tabs">
     <div class="tabalign">
     <button class="btn tab" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">
                    Back To Unit Counter
                </button>
     </div>
   </header>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
  <div class="tile">
    <div id="calendar-container">
      <table id="calendar-table">
        <div class="spacing">
        <span class="btncontainer"> 
        <button class="button buttonPrevious"><</button>
            <h1 id="calendar-title">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <button class="button buttonNext">></button>
      </h1>
          </div>
          </s>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tue</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thu</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td id="td1"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
          <td>27</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="date-text"></button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the text is coming from the other page? If you add the button to this code with some sort of placeholder text (not coming from another page), does it work? Are there any errors in your dev console?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have two pages one is a click counter I am using to count work done for the day. I am currently saving the total from each day to that page. I want to take the total and add it to my calendar on page 2. The codepen for the click counter is https://codepen.io/Jonbeckner/pen/NWzdKoZ page 1 is where my totalUnits element is.

Comment: I'll be saving the total to local storage which I'm familiar with. It's just getting the innerText from page one into the td for today on page 2 where I'm struggling. I have not been able to append text to the td corresponding to today's date.

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Keep in mind StackOverflow is meant to be a collection of searchable, programming-related questions and answers. Your question should be simplistic enough that it can be applied to more than just your extremely specific situation. Your problem statement is also not very clear. Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/10601203). https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/